# SceneKit SceneView pointOfView == nil causes objects to not move

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit, sceneview

I'm trying to figure out how SceneKit works and came across a strange behaviour.
if I set up SceneView with `pointOfView == nil` changing other nodes position sops working: `carNode.worldPosition.x = 100` won't change node's position on the screen.
As far as I understand in case of pointOfView being nil default camera is created but what causes nodes to stop moving? My understanding that matrix calculations still should work the same in this case, no?

Comment: does it really not move, or can't you just see it, because the pointOfVIew is nil? is anything displayed on screen? (why do you set the PoV to nil?)

Comment: @ZAY oh yeah, sorry for the unclear explanation. I can see the model on the screen and the property does change, it's just that I don't see the movement on the screen like the camera is always pointed out to the model. I set it to nil once by mistake actually and now just curious why it happens because it doesn't seem like a standard opengl behaviour.

Comment: I never tested such a case, where I was setting the PoV to nil. But okay, it could probably result in some strange behaviour. So, it seems, everything is good? Or do you need further assistance?

Comment: @ZAY Well, yeah, I mean it works in the end I was just curious about such a behaviour :).